# Creating a table showing totals from a variable

Tags: r, data.table

I am working on this file for own practice, Master.csv file, from http://www3.amherst.edu/~nhorton/r2/datasets/Master.csv. I want to create a table that shows how many people in the data set are from each birth country.So far this is the code I tried though I am not sure whether I did the right thing. Still new to R. Any help?

```
dat<-read.csv("http://www3.amherst.edu/~nhorton/r2/datasets/Master.csv",
    header=TRUE,sep=",")
  library(data.table)
  DT <- as.data.table(dat)
  setkey(DT, birthCountry)
  y<-DT[, lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm=TRUE), .(birthCountry)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DT = fread("http://www3.amherst.edu/~nhorton/r2/datasets/Master.csv")

DT[,.N,by=birthCountry]
                birthCountry     N
 1:                      USA 15421
 2:                Venezuela   256
 3:                     D.R.   516
 4:                   Mexico   111
 5:                   Panama    51
 ... snip

DT[,.N,by=birthCountry][order(-N)]
                birthCountry     N
 1:                      USA 15421
 2:                     D.R.   516
 3:                            346
 4:                Venezuela   256
 5:                     P.R.   231
 ...snip
```

Answer (score 0):

If each row of the `.csv` file represents a unique individual, you can use the `table` function in base R.

```
table(dat$birthCountry)
```

Comment: What if I wanted to find average height of all people in the data set that have a player ID and a manager ID?